# Default handler for delete command eclipse

Tags: eclipse, command, eclipse-rcp

I am working on an application based on the Eclipse RCP framwork. I am trying to override the standard delete command, given a set of conditions are true. What **I have done** so far is:
**1.** I created a custom handler
**2.** defined the necessary extensions. (my custom command with activeWhen and enabledWhen clauses, connection to the handler and a menuContribution for it to be included in a popup menu)
**3.** created a custom propertyTester

As far as I understood from previous stackoverflow questions, for my command to be chosen instead of the default delete command, it needs to have a more specific activeWhen clause.

What **I would like to know** is:
**1.** does the delete command have a default handlerand can I overwrite it in any other way than specifying a more specific activeWhen clause?
**2.** Could I theoretically hide the standard delete command with an activity?

Comment: In eclipse goto Window -> Preferences- > General -> Keys, sort on binding, search Del key delete the binding by clicking on "Remove Binding"

Comment: I have edited the question a little bit to frame the context correctly.

Comment: As an alternative could you use a delete participant (extension point `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.deleteParticipants`) to do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved:**
I solved it by adapting the standard delete handler class' behaviour to handle cases fulfilling the provided set of conditions differently.